# Как в android studio поменять размер панелей?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

В самом коде я знаю про колёсико + ctrl и использую, но вот эти панели не знаю как изменить. Также архитектуру сбоку более крупной можно сделать как-то?
[image]

Comment: File=>Settings...=>Appearance. Поставить галку на `Override default fonts by` и выбрать тип и размер шрифта. Это изменит размер всех значков и подписей.